# In mySQL I am looking to count the number of different counties

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Table is as follows

```
- STUDENT TABLE
- STUDENT NAME    -  COUNTY
- John           -  Waterford
- Chris          -  Waterford
- Anne            - Tipperary
- Paul            - Cork
- Thomas         - Cork
```

Clearly form the table 3 differrent counties exist, I am looking for a count statement to show that three different counties exist.

Currently I am at

```
SELECT COUNT(county)
FROM Student;
```

I have tried Grouping and I can seem to count everything in the table bar the number of counties, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `group by`

```
SELECT county,COUNT(county)
FROM Student group by county;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `DISTINCT` to count each county only once:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT county)
FROM Student;
```

Comment: Thanks a million, perfect.

Comment: @BernardBonjoThompson May I ask what does it mean? Comment, accept answer, unaccept answer and accept another?

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY clause in you query

```
SELECT COUNT(county) FROM Student GROUP BY `county`;
```

also you can add DISTINCT as "lad2025" suggested.